# Sharing external hard drive for backups and file exchange by Mac and PC through wi-fi

Tags: windows-7, macos, wireless-networking, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I've had problems using a BUFALLO 1T HDD for both Time Machine backups on the Mac (Intel based) and system backups on the PC (Win 7) as well as for file sharing for both of the computers via wifi network. The HDD is connected to AirPort extreme via USB. AirPort Extreme delivers wifi signal to both of the computers, phones and pads. Is it possible at all, or do I need dedicated HDDs for each purpose? Here is what I was trying to do:

I used Disk utility to make 3 partitions:
1. 500 GB - MacOS extended/GUID for Time Machine backups
2. 300 GB - exFAT for file sharing
3. 199 GB - exFAT for Win backups

Unfortunately this didn't work for me:
1. When HDD connected to each of the computers via USB - Mac recognizes all partitions, Time Machine can write to them. PC archiving doesn't work on exFAT partitions but recognizes them as local drives. 
2. When HDD is accessed via wifi (connected to AirPort Extreme via USB) - Mac recognizes only MacOS partition, Time Machine lets choose it but gives an error when making a backup. PC doesn't see anything at all. 
3. Likewise I attempted to format the 3d partition as NTFS, but this didn't help much except that Time Machine didn't even see any volumes at all to choose from.

Anyone can kindly help me out with that? I'd appreciate any help!